# read.csv(file.choose()) problem in StatET/Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, r

When trying to read a csv file in StatET/Eclipse (OS X 10.6, Eclipse 3.6) using the following command:

```
 read.csv(file.choose(),header=T)
```

I get the response:

```
Error in file.choose() : file choice cancelled
```

The command works as expected in 'R' itself and reading a named csv file works in StatET. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Supplemental Info**

 I note that the Error Log shows: 

    An error occurred when exec RJ UI command 'chooseFile'

 and the Exception Stack Trace begins:
 
`org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.NullPointerException)` 

then a long list beginning: `at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4083)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: submitting this question to statet-user@lists.r-forge.r-project.org secured a response from Stephan Wahlbrink

> Updating StatET to 0.9.2 should fix
>   the problem.

Updating from within Eclipse (Help > Check for Updates) to the latest version (site-statet-00.09.02  [ 2011-01-03 | stable | Eclipse 3.6 ]) did indeed fix the problem.

Many thanks to Stephan.

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems ok for me. My platform is StatET/Eclipse(win7-x64, Eclipse 3.6).

Only when I click 'cancel' in the select file dialog, it will give that error message.