# "Error in file.choose() : file choice cancelled" ~ RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Similar to: [read.csv(file.choose()) problem in StatET/Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733556/read-csvfile-choose-problem-in-statet-eclipse)

In the following code, a user is prompted to:

1. Choose a file
2. Do some things in a loop
3. Choose another file.

However in step 3 I get the error ***"Error in file.choose() : file choice cancelled"***. This error occurs in RStudio (however the code works fine in base R).

```
# This works 
f1 <- file.choose()

# Something happens in here which will cause the error at the end
msg <- "Click YES"
test <- TRUE
while(test == TRUE) {
  # user chooses from menu
  letter <- menu(letters, graphics=TRUE, title="Select a letter and press OK")
  # user inputs a string
  str <- winDialogString(message="Press OK", default="xyz")
  # user decides if they want to repeat loop
  question <- winDialog(type = "yesno", message = msg)
  test <- ifelse(question == "YES", TRUE, FALSE)
  msg <- "Click NO"
}

# This will result in: "Error in file.choose() : file choice cancelled"
f2 <- file.choose()
```

Should I be doing something special to make it work in RStudio?

I am using RStudio 0.98.932 on Windows 7 Pro x64

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.0.2
```